# testing sencha application

Tags: testing, mobile, extjs

I want to develop a sencha application who use a picture and make some modification on it. I want the user to be able to select the photo via phone camera or from photos that he already has in his phone.

I've searched all over the sencha documentation and found a solution to do this first step but I can't figure up how to test it.

I mean how can I test my application on the mobile?

I will be very grateful if someone will help me how to test a simple hello world sencha application on the mobile, because I'm really stuck at this step.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test it on an actual device, you'll have to use PhoneGap (now called Apache Cordova). I'm not sure which device you have, but there's a list of tutorials to get you started here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html

Then all you have to do is move any of the files Sencha has generated into the assets folder.

If you're looking for a tutorial on how to get started with Sencha, here's a good one:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/hello-world/